# How do I concatenate Strings in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Obviously there are multiple ways to concatenate Strings in Kotlin:

1. processString(pojo.name + " " + pojo.value)
2. processString("${pojo.name} ${pojo.value}")
3. processString(pojo.name.plus(" ").plus(pojo.value))

Of course also with StringBuilder, concat()-Method etc.
Those will work.

But my question is, why is Android Studio proposing "convert concatenation to template" and converts 1. to 2. ? **Are there any speed advantages with 2.? So wahts the advantage using 2.?**

Comment: There's no difference, under the hood `StringBuilder` is allocated either way. Only if you're building `String` in a loop it's better to manually create one `StringBuilder` and `concat` for each item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** String Templates are the most idiomatic way to concatenate strings

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#strings) states

> Note that in most cases using string templates or raw strings is preferable to string concatenation.

String templates are basically the same as regular concatenation (using `+`) but **more compact, idiomatic and equally efficient**. Both variants are implemented using `StringBuilder`s in the byte code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the 1. approach comes from java. Of course the compiler knows what's happening but the suggestion is to use it in Kotlin like the 2. point is stated. Using the 2. approach is better because you might get confused with the `+` (`plus()`) operator that is used to sum up numbers.